# Laravel test passes auth middleware but fails Auth::user() with data providers

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-authentication, phpunit

I am testing my Laravel application with the integrated PHPUnit configuration and I have problems with the authentication of a user inside a test.

I have this test (shortened)

```
public function testShowEditForm($user, $expectedStatus, $expectedLocation, $expectedSee, $expectedDontSee) {
    if ($user !== null)
        $this->actingAs($user);

    // $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user); -> This is true!

    $response = $this->get("/objects/edit/");

    $response->assertStatus($expectedStatus);

    // [...]
}
```

with this data provider:

```
public function showEditFormProvider() {
    return [
        'allowedUser' => [
            UserGenerator::getControllingUser(),
            200,
            null,
            ["something"],
            []
        ]
    ];
}
```

The `UserGenerator::getControllingUser()` just triggers the User Factory, adds some rights and returns the user object.

The tested method (also shortened):

```
public function edit($object_id = null) {
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id); // Auth::user() returns null
    // [...]
}
```

The route for this method is encapsuled inside the `"middleware" => "auth"` part in the routes/web.php

Problem:
The data provider is correctly called, it *passes the middleware* but the `Auth::user()` call in the `edit()` method *returns null* - so the authentication seems to have failed anyway regardless the passing through the middleware?

- If I replace the parameter $user in the testShowEditForm directly
  with UserGenerator::getControllingUser(), it works (but this isn't a
  good workaround because I have a lot of test cases and so I need the
  data providers).
- So I worked around by calling the data provider by
  $this->showEditFormProvider() in the first line of the test method
  testShowEditForm() - but it gets called twice (what is the correct
  behaviour according to this <sup>1</sup>). But this is also not the
  ideal workaround, because if I create an object in the provider to
  test, it gets created also twice and so the assertions fail.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I already searched a lot for this topic and the `actingAs()`/`be()` methods in the testing method seem to be the best practice for mocking a logged in user.

<sup>1</sup> "All data providers are executed before both the call to the setUpBeforeClass static method and the first call to the setUp method." https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($user); it's type of mocking but I'm using it usually in unit testing not functional testing. You can also give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.8 it worked using

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
```

instead of

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id); // Auth::user() returns null
```

inside the Controller.
I have no idea why, but maybe it will help some searching dev in the future.
Funnily enough, since Laravel 6 (currently my app is on 6.10.0), no more problems, even with the "old" implementation.